# issue With Contact Form 7 submit button

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been using contact form 7 in WordPress for very long,now I am facing an issue in one of my sites. The contact form 7 button is not clickable at all. There is no console error initially.

Please suggest the solution for this.

Here is the link : https://www.redbangle.com/contact/

Comment: but now  i tried to send one dummy mail, it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening up your network tab you can see a more in depth response when trying to submit the form.

I received the following:

```
{
"mailSent":false,
"into":"#wpcf7-f3241-p3238-o1",
"captcha":null,
"message":"One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.",
"invalids":[{
    "into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.Email",
    "message":"The e-mail address entered is invalid.",
    "idref":null
  },{
    "into":"span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.Mobile",
    "message":"The telephone number is invalid.",
    "idref":null
  }]
}
```